# Life Studio Disk for Mac

Tags: mac

Will the **Hitachi Life Studio Desk** work on my Mac running latest IOS? I don't seem to find answer. I brought this in 2010 with help of a friend. I was using Windows prior. I am thinking that for the past years, it wasn't or will not work on iMac?

Comment: This is a portable hard drive. Have you tried just plugging it in?

Answer (score 0):

The best link I found was [this ZDNet article from 2010](https://www.zdnet.com/article/hitachi-lifestudio/). I couldn't find any information about this drive on [hitachi.com](http://hitachi.com) (except for a press release without any useful information).

The ZDNet article states:

> The LifeStudio software also indexes your content - on the Hitachi drive and your PC or **Mac** as well as on Facebook, Flickr and Picasa, and presents them as thumbnails on a Cool Iris-powered 3D wall. [...]

So it seems that there must be some Mac software for it out there. But it's probably totally outdated and for an ancient version of MacOS. I guess you should expect it to work only as an USB-2.0 external HDD.